# Is there a site that shows the current GPS position of active cruise ships?

Tags: online-resources, cruising, gps-navigation

The Queen Mary 2 is currently in port in Sydney. I'd love to see it but am bedridden at present.  However, to leave port it must pass the window of where I am.  I'm wondering if there's a website that plots either just the QM2 position (I tried [seascanner's QM2 page](http://www.seascanner.com/schiffsposition.php?schiff=queen+mary+2) but sadly it's exceeded its maps API quota so isn't working), or ideally, like flightradar24 for planes, a version for cruise ships?

(And to clarify, seascanner wouldn't work as an answer, unless it has a different page that I've not found that is presently working)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A bit more searching and I've found [Vesselfinder's QM2 page](http://www.vesselfinder.com/?imo=9241061).

Getting closer, I've found [Crusein Me Ship Tracker](http://www.cruisin.me/cruise-ship-tracker/), which looks promising...

[image]

And The Cruse Village has a [Live Ship Tracker](http://www.thecruisevillage.com/live-cruise-ship-tracker.phtml):

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are only three interesting things in the world to cruise to: Caribbean sun, Scandinavian landscape and Mediterranean cultural heritage.

Comment: @Alexander pfft that's half a map. Lots in NZ and Aus, I'd love to do an Antarctica Cruise or up the Alaska route too.

Comment: @Alexander In the summer, you will see tons of them going to Alaska. In the winter, not so much.

Answer (score 6):

There's [MarineTraffic](http://www.marinetraffic.com/), but it [lists the Queen Mary 2](http://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/shipid:371681/imo:9241061/mmsi:310627000/vessel:QUEEN%20MARY%202) as currently out-of-range of its terrestrial AIS feed. They also offer satellite-base AIS feeds, but you need a paying account for that. The free feed should be sufficient to track ships while near land.

(AIS = Automatic Identification System, a VHF-based system used by ships to broadcast their position and other data to each other)